# Common component for Input field in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a common components for all input types.
I am using angular version 8.0.1

But i am facing some issues.

In parent component i am writing code as follows

```
<form class="" [formGroup]="signUpForm">
    <app-input-field [inputFieldParams]="
                  { 
                    type: 'text',
                    class: 'form-control rounded-0', 
                    label: 'First Name',
                    placeholder: 'First Name',
                    formControlName: 'first_name',
                    id: 'first_name',
                    mode: '',
                    formGroup: 'signUpForm',
                    value: pageMode != 'addMode' ? userData.first_name : '',
                    disabled: 'false'  
                  }" 
                  (getInputValueOnChange)="setInputValueOnChange('first_name', $event)">
                </app-input-field>
                <show-errors [control]="signUpForm.controls.first_name"></show-errors>
</form>
```

and in child component html file it is as follows

```
<div [formGroup]="inputFieldParams.formGroup" class="input-group" >
    <label for="usr">{{ inputFieldParams.label }}
        <span *ngIf="inputFieldParams.required"class="required">*</span>
    </label>
<input 
    formControlName= {{inputFieldParams.formControlName}}
    type={{inputFieldParams.type}} 
    class={{inputFieldParams.class}} 
    placeholder={{inputFieldParams.placeholder}} 
    id={{inputFieldParams.id}} 
    (change)="onChangeInput($event.target.value)" 
    [(ngModel)]="inputFieldParams.value" 
    [disabled]="inputFieldParams.disabled">
</div>
```

and in ts file

```
export class InputFieldComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() inputFieldParams: any;
    @Output() getInputValueOnChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
    constructor() { }
}
```

But i am getting following error

```
TypeError: this.form.get is not a function
```

I tried many ways, but i am not sure to achieve it in angular to have a common component.

Comment: You are using ngModel and formControls? where is the this.form property defined? Post your full code please

Comment: The code of "TypeError: this.form.get is not a function" is not shown. What exactly is your goal by wrapping the input?

Comment: inputFieldParams.formGroup is a string, and you need that was a FormGroup. By the way, if only need pass a formControl, pass a formControl and use directly [formControl]="inputFieldParams.control" -avoid introucing an innecesary formGroup in your child-